# Flex not taking width

Tags: html, css, html-lists, flexbox

I have the following responsive flex layout but the `.image-holder` won't take the correct width - it just seems to be resized according to how much text is in the `text-holder`

```css
.pdf-link-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1em 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.pdf-link-list .column {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.pdf-link-list .link {
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.pdf-link-list .image-holder {
  padding-right: 15px;
  width: 35%;
}
.pdf-link-list .width100 {
  width: 100%;
}
.pdf-link-list .text-holder {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul id="laying-patterns-links" class="pdf-link-list">
  <li class="column link-holder">
    <a href="#" class="track-event link" data-category="ProductPDFDownload" data-action="" data-label="">
      <span class="image-holder"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x359" alt="" class="width100"></span>
      <span class="text-holder">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="column link-holder">
    <a href="#" class="track-event link" data-category="ProductPDFDownload" data-action="" data-label="">
      <span class="image-holder"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x359" alt="" class="width100"></span>
      <span class="text-holder">Proin varius magna vitae magna porttitor tincidunt</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="column link-holder">
    <a href="#" class="track-event link" data-category="ProductPDFDownload" data-action="" data-label="">
      <span class="image-holder"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x359" alt="" class="width100"></span>
      <span class="text-holder">Sed vestibulum aliquet ligula, at suscipit libero</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="column link-holder">
    <a href="#" class="track-event link" data-category="ProductPDFDownload" data-action="" data-label="">
      <span class="image-holder"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x359" alt="" class="width100"></span>
      <span class="text-holder">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Does anyone know what I am missing from this, I thought because I gave the `.image-holder` a `width` and the `.text-holder` a `flex-grow:1`, the `.image holder` should stay the same whilst the text holder expands.

I'm new to flex so would like to understand why it is behaving in the way it is

**EDIT**

Sorry the fixed width for the image-holder above is just for demonstration as the real values didn't show the problem well on the snippet.  The real values for image-holder width is:

```
width: 35%; min-width: 100px; max-width:250px; (instead of width:150px;)
```

Why aren't all the image-holders 35% wide if all the images inside them are the same size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give your `.image-holder` a `flex:1` and then in `img` set `max-width:100%`

```css
.pdf-link-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1em 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.pdf-link-list .column {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.pdf-link-list .link {
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.pdf-link-list .image-holder {
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 35%;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 250px;
  flex: 1
}
.pdf-link-list .width100 {
  max-width: 100%
}
.pdf-link-list .text-holder {
  flex: 1
}
```

```html
<ul id="laying-patterns-links" class="pdf-link-list">
  <li class="column link-holder">
    <a href="#" class="track-event link" data-category="ProductPDFDownload" data-action="" data-label="">
      <span class="image-holder"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x359" alt="" class="width100"></span>
      <span class="text-holder">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="column link-holder">
    <a href="#" class="track-event link" data-category="ProductPDFDownload" data-action="" data-label="">
      <span class="image-holder"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x359" alt="" class="width100"></span>
      <span class="text-holder">Proin varius magna vitae magna porttitor tincidunt</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="column link-holder">
    <a href="#" class="track-event link" data-category="ProductPDFDownload" data-action="" data-label="">
      <span class="image-holder"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x359" alt="" class="width100"></span>
      <span class="text-holder">Sed vestibulum aliquet ligula, at suscipit libero</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="column link-holder">
    <a href="#" class="track-event link" data-category="ProductPDFDownload" data-action="" data-label="">
      <span class="image-holder"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x359" alt="" class="width100"></span>
      <span class="text-holder">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry dippas, please see my edit - I can't give the image a fixed width

Comment: @Pete see updated answer, (I thought you wanted a fixed `width`)

Comment: ah, that's got it.  What's the difference between flex:1 and flex-grow:1?

Comment: `flex:1` it is a shorthand  for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis` combined. The second and third parameters (`flex-shrink` and `flex-basis`) are optional. Default is `0 1 auto`. You can follow this great [guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 2):

Use `min-width` additionally to `width` for your `.image-holder` class. That way those elements will really be at least `150px` wide.

Comment: Sorry, I should say that I have tried this as my code actually uses `width: 35%; min-width: 100px; max-width:250px;` but for the above snippet demonstration it was better to just show the width as a fixed number and figure out why that isn't being used

Answer (score 1):

Set [flex-shrink](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink) to zero on the `.image-holder`. This prevents the image from resizing inside the flex box.

```
flex-shrink: 0;
```

By default, the value is set to 1. Allowing the `image-holder` to resize to and adjust to the flex.